# ParMap values method alternative

Tags: scala, parallel-collections

[ParMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap) (in Scala 2.9) doesn't seem to have a .values method.  Why is this, and how can I work around it if I'm particularly keen on maintaining a parallel chain of processing such as the following?

```
myParSeq.collect{case i: Interesting => i}.groupBy(_.content).values. ...
```

Comment: Why can't you replace `.values` with `.map(_._2)`?

Comment: Hadn't though of that, will do.  Was just surprised that it wasn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently an oversight.

[Adding the missing ParMap and GenMap methods.](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/68031b3af11a2f79b186607f44d5c327051d19bd)

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_06).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import collection.parallel.immutable._
import collection.parallel.immutable._

scala> ParMap("a"->1)
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap[String,Int] = ParMap(a -> 1)

scala> res0.values
res1: scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[Int] = ParIterable(1)
```

How about:

```
$ scala29
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Map("a"->1, "b"->2).par
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap[java.lang.String,Int] = ParMap(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> .unzip._2
res1: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParIterable[Int] = ParVector(1, 2)
```